# Find an updated NSManagedObject via NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using some ManagedObjects with relationships: Customers have many Tasks.

During a server update, I need to update some customers and delete some tasks.

Obviously due to the deletion of a Task, the corresponding Customer is getting updated.
I debugged it and I can find the Customer in the updatedObjects set of the Context.

Now I need to search for a specific Customer using a NSPredicate (customerId == 123) and a FetchRequest.
The problem is that this request doesn't return a result. Obviously because the customer is changed.

This all runs in a kind of transaction, so I don't want to save the context between deleting the Task and searching for the customer.

What am I doing wrong? Or how do I deal with this scenario? Before searching via NSFetchRequest, I could iterate over the updatedObjects in the context, but I don't think this is a good solution?!

Comment: The fetch should return the updated Customer, even if it has not yet been saved.  Does your predicate refer only to the customerId?  Deleting tasks should not affect the customerId (unless the delete rule for the relationship is "cascade") so I think your problem may be more to do with the predicate.

Comment: No, the fetch doesn't return anything. Yes, predicate has only "customerId = 123".

Answer (score 0):

When ever your deleting the Task you need to remove mapping as well

```
- (void)removeTaskObject:(Task *)value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with an new editing context for the changes to the data (removing a task). And using the main context (which is not yet affected by the changes) for the fetch. This is working.